# Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_driver could not be converted to int

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_driver could not be converted to
>   int
>   Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

My controller:

```
public function loaddatasetoran($nisku){
    $query = $this->MTransaksi->loadsetoran($nisku);
    die(json_encode($query));
}
```

My model:

```
public function loadsetoran($nisku){
    $load = $this->db->where('nis', $nisku);
    return $this->db->get('tb_setoran', $load);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your model to this :

```
public function loadsetoran($nisku) {
   return $this->db->where('nis', $nisku);
               ->get('tb_setoran');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
public function loadsetoran($nisku) {
    $this->db->where('nis', $nisku);
    return $this->db->get('tb_setoran')->row();
}
```